# Como fazer consultas mais rápidas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, time

Como posso eu tornar mais rápidos as consultas a uma tabela `MySQL` com 3 milhões de registos, a tabela tem apenas 4 colunas, e demora-me quase 5 segundos a retornar dados. Os campos aos quais eu faço procura têm `index`. A `Query` retorna perto de 50 mil registos e é executada pelo `MySQL WorkBench`. Deixo mais algumas informações abaixo e se necessário posso disponibilizar mais informação.

Query:

```
SELECT campo2, campo3, campo4 FROM tabela2 
WHERE campo2=25 AND campo3>='2016-09-01 00:00' AND campo3<='2016-10-01 00:00'
```

Estrutura Tabela2:

```
id     - bigint
campo2 - int         - index
campo3 - timestamp   - index
campo4 - float
```

Alguém me consegue ajudar com alguma coisa?

Comment: Fica difícil responder sem que você poste mais informações como o  modelo da tabelas envolvidas e query que está lenta.

Comment: Amigo, acredito que você consiga melhorar consideravelmente o tempo de execução da query trocando a forma de comparação das datas pelo comando BETWEEN. Seria interessante você postar o modelo do banco para que possamos analisar o problema melhor.

Comment: @GOKUSSJGod e mexer no my.ini pode resolver alguma coisa?

Comment: Certo. Você precisa trazer todos os campos da tabela mesmo? (SELECT * FROM tabela2...)

Comment: @GeovanedaSilvadeJesus não, posso deixar o id

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47578/discussion-on-question-by-tmc-como-tornar-querys-mais-rapidos)

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo como otimizar muito mais a sua query no quesito de banco de dados, é uma query simples com índice apropriado. Mas de qualquer forma de uma olhada no plano de execução para confirmar.

Supondo que a query tenha sido executada direto no BD, o único outro gargalo que posso imaginar (além de alguma configuração obscura que tenha sido feita) é o hardware.